# Texture coordinates don't correspond to cv::Mat Coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv, coordinates

What I want is to show a marker to the camera and, having found, overlay it with an image, for example this: (let's call **image**)

[image]

What I do is:

1) I open my webcam with opencv. I load **image**. I detect the marker in the captured frame. Calculating the coordinates of the marker with respect to **frame**.

```
#define WIDTH              600 //opengl window width
#define HEIGHT             440 //opengl window height
VideoCapture cap;
GLint window;
GLuint *textures = new GLuint[2];
vector <Point2f> coord(4);
int flag =0;
// Capture next frame
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    flip(frame,frame,1);
    aruco::CameraParameters CamParam;
    aruco::MarkerDetector MDetector;
    std::vector <Marker> Markers;
    float MarkerSize=170;

    //marker detection
    CamParam.readFromXMLFile("parametri_camera.yml");
    CamParam.resize( frame.size());
    MDetector.detect(frame, Markers, CamParam, MarkerSize);
    Mat image = imread("Immagine.png");
    if (Markers.size()!=0) flag =1;
    else flag =0;
    for (int i=0; i< Markers.size(); i++) {
        coord_marker(frame, Markers[i], CamParam, coord);
    }
```

2) I transform/convert **image** and **frame** into two textures.

```
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4,frame.cols, frame.rows, 0, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame.data);

glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4,image.cols, image.rows, 0, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);
```

3) I show the two textures, where `textures[1]` is positioned in correspondence of the coordinates of the marker.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Set Projection Matrix
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0); 

    // Switch to Model View Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    // Draw a textured quad
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(WIDTH, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, HEIGHT);
    glEnd(); 

    if(flag ==1) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((coord[1].x)),(GLfloat)(coord[1].y));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((coord[2].x)),(GLfloat)(coord[2].y));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((coord[3].x)),(GLfloat)(coord[3].y));
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((coord[0].x)),(GLfloat)(coord[0].y)); 
    glEnd();
    }
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, `textures[1]` is shifted relative to the marker.
What am I missing? It looks like I need to do some transformation/conversion fom Mat coordinates to Texture coordinates. But how?

Comment: no idea? It is very important for me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in my code.

Wrong to set the openGL window size (window size was smaller than captured frame). I had to size the window with the size of the captured frame (640x480). In this way, the coordinates of the marker in the Mat frame  correspond to the coordinates of the marker in the `textures[1]`.

```
#define WIDTH              640 //opengl window width and captured frame width
#define HEIGHT             480 //opengl window height and captured frame height
```

[image]

Hope this will help someone!